# How to connect bluetooth sim808 in Swift

Tags: swift, ios-bluetooth

I want pair and connect to Bluetooth sim808 (Classic) with Swift. try use `BluetoothManager` Freamework class, but could not do anything. after pair and connect how to send/receive data (talk with Bluetooth device)?

[This link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387) describe profile, and i want use HID or HFP (if i have to) but I do not have any information...

Please Help. Thank

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by `BluetoothManager`. I assume you mean `CBCentralManager` or `CBPeripheralManager`. In either case, there is no access in iOS to classic Bluetooth. The framework Core Bluetooth is exclusively for BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy), which is a completely different protocol.

You cannot access HID or HFP from an iOS app. The only profile you can access is GATT (or L2CAP in iOS 11).

Comment: Thanks Rob, but look this link: https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee. this repository use BluethoothManager Framework. and search/detect classic bluetooth well.

Comment: This relies on a private framework. Are you saying you don't plan to publish this app? From the docs you linked, the author doesn't seem to be claiming it can read/write, just scan. While clearly there is some private framework somewhere that can do this (in a way that you cannot ship through App Store), you probably want to make it clearer in your question that you're looking for an undocumented and unsupported solution, and the version of iOS you need it to work with. I'm not aware of anyone who has reverse engineered this piece of iOS.

Comment: You probably should also reach out to the author of the BeeTee, since they've clearly tried to reverse engineer it, and they can give you pointers in what is known and not known.

Comment: nearly, but this app same work and upload in App Store: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bluetooth-smart-scanner/id509978131?mt=8

Comment: That app scans for BLE devices (also called "Bluetooth Smart" or "Bluetooth 4.0"). That's completely supported. Do you see somewhere that it's claiming support for Bluetooth classic? All the screens are showing GATT information.

Comment: Probably the most powerful app in this space is LightBlue. It's also BLE-only. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-explorer/id557428110

Comment: Bluetooth Smart Scanner, find both classic and BLE bluetooth. before BLE how to work Hands-free and other ios third-party bluetooth App?

Comment: @Sina Playing around with Bluetooth Smart Scanner, I don't see any evidence of it discovering classic Bluetooth. All the results look like BLE. Why do you believe it's classic? Note that a lot of headphones also advertise BLE for configuration (not audio), so seeing headphones doesn't mean that it's discovered a classic connection. I don't know what "Hands-free" means in this context. Core Bluetooth (BLE-only) was added in iOS 5. What Bluetooth apps were available before that?

Comment: It is possible to detect a *connected* classic BT audio device using AVAudioSession, but access is extremely limited. It's also possible to get a bit more access if your device is under the MFi program (Made for iPhone) and you use the External Accessory framework, but that doesn't help scanner apps. BTW, I work full-time on Bluetooth headphones and am extremely interested in any AppStore shippable techniques you find to detect and manipulate classic connection. It would help me a lot. But I don't believe they exist.